# Anchor link landing in wrong position

Tags: html, hyperlink, position, anchor

Probably a stupid question, but I honestly can't wrap my head around what's going wrong here.

http://harrisonfjord.com/thinkinc/

A site I'm building at the moment. I want to make an anchor link at http://harrisonfjord.com/thinkinc/index.php#sponsors. I've set up the anchor to occur just before  in the following code:

```
<a name="sponsors"></a>
    <div class="sponsors">
        <div class="sponsors-left">
            <h2>Sponsors</h2>
                <p>Support the lovely folks who support us! Visit their websites, join their mailing lists and peruse their wares. They are all highly-deserving of your custom, and we're thrilled to have each and everyone one of them on-board!</p>
            </div>
```

However, when you click on the anchor link it lands about halfway down the div. I thought it might have been a problem with the images loading after the anchor link loads, so I manually put in widths/heights for all of the  tags. I also did the same for the cufon text replacement in the title bar.

None of that helped, so now I turn to you. The anchor is also not working in Firefox, for whatever reason. Any thoughts on what I've done wrong here?

Cheers!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think the problem is resulting from the anchors with no contents that you are using.

Also, it appears that `name=` has been [deprecated in favor](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#h-4.10) of `id=` as a fragment identifier in certain elements (including `A`) which makes a kind of sense as ID attributes are unique whereas NAME attributes are not so guaranteed.

I'd try sticking the fragment identifier in the actual renderable entity such as:

```
<h2 id="sponsors">Sponsors</h2>
```

and see where that gets you. Incidentally, it looks like a good conference, I hope you get a comp admission.

Comment: Aha! Got it, worked a charm, thanks mate. Incidentally - I'm one of the conference organiser, no web dev! So not only will I be at the conference, but also drinking whiskey with the speakers :)

Answer (score 16):

I got the exact same issue in Firefox and solved it with this (same as sasi answer but more generic - it detect if there is an anchor in the url and scroll to it):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if(window.location.hash.length > 0) {
        window.scrollTo(0, $(window.location.hash).offset().top);
    }
});
```

It seems it's a well known issue, see https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=60307

Comment: This worked for me on a page where I was using a table-of-contents js snippet. On only one page of many following the same pattern, the initial scroll was not taking into account the added text from the TOC.

Comment: Thanks @vard. I really had this solution did not work until the end and I set the timer with a minimum delay. Now works in Mozilla perfectly.   `if (window.location.hash.length > 0) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      window.scrollTo(0, $(window.location.hash).offset().top);
    }, 100);
  }` See you.

Answer (score 4):

I got problem in iphone for links with fragments, having 
`<a href="#info">TYPES OF INFORMATION WE COLLECT</a>`, correctly linking to 
`<h3 id="info">TYPES OF INFORMATION WE COLLECT</h3>`.

That wasn't working properly, and I fixed with a solution like this (using jQuery):

```
window.scrollTo(0,$('#info').offset().top);
```

Comment: Nice workaround: I used it because firefox wasn't landing in the right place the first time, i.e. after following a link with a fragment, but requesting that exact URL on firefox's bar made the browser land in the right place.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this with a trick, I have put an empty span element with the required ID and a line break before the div

```
<span id="sponsors">&nbsp;</span>
<br>
<div class="sponsors">
    <div class="sponsors-left">
        <h2>Sponsors</h2>
            <p>Support the lovely folks who support us! Visit their websites, join their mailing lists and peruse their wares. They are all highly-deserving of your custom, and we're thrilled to have each and everyone one of them on-board!</p>
    </div>
</div>

<a href="#sponsors">GO TO SPONSORS</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what standard your page is trying to conform to, but it is full of errors:

http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fharrisonfjord.com%2Fthinkinc%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Some of them so severe, for example:

- Unable to Determine Parse Mode!
- No DOCTYPE found, and unknown root element. Aborting validation.

that the validator gives up. Contrasted with a page like gnu.org

http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=www.gnu.org&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

You should be pleased that the site renders at all.

Comment: Good point, I didn't think validation affected this kind of thing so was gonna do it after. I'll get on it now and report back if it's still broken, cheers!

Comment: Ok, back and now fixed, validated as HTML 4.0 Transitional. However, anchor still not working! Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with scrolling to the wrong position and I fixed it by disabling the Development Tools panel in Chrome :) Apparently Chrome calculates the position incorrectly when DevTools is open.