# one page website anchor only works properly in chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, anchor, mozilla

I created my online portfolio and it's one page, I used anchor tags on the top menu which work perfectly in chrome but in explorer and Firefox when you click the skills tab it lands somewhere in the middle of my work anyone know why a simple tag might not load right in some browsers??

[Link to the website with the issue](http://www.loganzendesign.com)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Anchor link landing in wrong position](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6826741/anchor-link-landing-in-wrong-position)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you make an anchor with an `<a>` element with the `name` parameter. To make an anchor, you need an `id`.

Example:

```
<div id="skill"/>
```

or with a `div` with some content:

```
<div id="skill">
...
</div>
```

The reason is that using the `name` attribute in the `<a>` attribute is **obsolete** since [html5](/questions/tagged/html5).

Documentation from the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a):

> This attribute is required in an anchor defining a target location within a page. A value for name is similar to a value for the id core attribute and 
>   should be an alphanumeric identifier unique to the document. Under the HTML 4.01 specification, id and name both can be used with the `<a>` element as long as they have identical values.

Comment: I'm not sure this is the answer, but the consensus seems to be that you should follow @Fralec's suggestion anyway. For a more in-depth explanation, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/484719/html-anchors-with-name-or-id

Comment: Updated my answer.